# rails admin keeps trying to access deleted model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I installed rails_admin gem. I had scaffolded a resource named account_types. It shows up successfully in rails admin. But when I git reverted my project to delete account_types, rails_admin is still trying to load the new resource account_types.

I tried the following.

Regenerating the rails_admin

```
rails g rails_admin:install
```

Clearing cache

```
rake tmp:clear
```

Uninstalling gem rails_admin

```
gem install rails_admin
```

Disabling caching in dev mode.

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

Searching entire project for traces of account_types.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I still had my old model file in the project.

models/account_types.rb

This github link helped me.

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2021